# В чем польза рекурсии?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия

Читал что "рекурсия обычно замедляет работу программы и расходует лишнюю память". Это во всех случаях? И какая еще от нее есть польза кроме как компактной записи кода? И в каких случаях она необходима?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Бытует мнение, что рекурсия является очень выразительным|естественным|няшечка|etc средством для реализации некоторых действий.

Рекурсия общего вида:

1. Замедляет, т.к. много ( в т.ч. бесконечно ) вызовов функций.
2. Расходует память, т.к. каждый вызов функции хранит данные в стеке

Есть ещё, т.н., хвостовая рекурсия. ( ИМХО - не рекурсия вовсе, а просто сахар для цикла ):

Суть в том, что результат вызова итерации хвостовой рекурсии - не обрабатывается предыдущим шагом, и копилятор/интерпритатор может заменить работу с такой функцией - на цикл, который лишён недостатков указанных выше.

1) Пример хвостовой рекурсии ( JS, факториал ):

```
function fact( step, res ){
    if ( step < 2 ) return res;
    else return fact( step - 1, res * step );
}

fact_10 = fact( 10, 1 );
```

2) Тот-же смысл, но обычная рекурсия:

```
function fact( step ){
    if ( step < 2 ) return 1;
    else return step * fact( step - 1 );
}

fact_10 = fact( 10 );
```

Разница, как уже указывал:

1. Результат вызова никак не используется ( просто проброс на уровень выше )
2. Результат вызова перед возвращением подвергается некой операции.

Вариант 1 легко ( алгоритм простой ) оптимизируется до такого кода:

```
function fact( num ){
  var res = 1;

  while( num > 1 ){
    res *= num;
    num--;
  }

  return res;
}
```

Либо совсем кратко ( но в asm - тоже самое ):

```
function fact( num ){
  var res = 1;

  while( num > 1 ) res *= num--;

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Тут спорный вопрос, что для чего является «сахаром». Скорее цикл является удобной оберткой для хвостовой рекурсии.

Comment: Если рекурсия имеет шанс стать бесконечной, это очень плохой код. Нужно обязательно обеспечить возможность ее завершения.

Comment: @mikillskegg, то же самое можно сказать и про обычный цикл. Конечно в цикле память сама по себе не утекает (если нет утечек:)), но все равно поставленная задача решена не будет.

Comment: @mikillskegg, само описание функций - тот-же факториал, подразумевает ( если опустить вопросы ёмкости), что в качестве n может быть передано бесконечно большое число, и именно это ( я так думаю ) в основном подразумевается по бесконечной рекурсией - т.е. возможность работать с бесконечно большими структурами за конечное время ( звучит странно;) )

Comment: @timka_s, что-то не понял, как это бесконечные структуры за конечное время:)

Comment: @timka_s, можно пример ?

Comment: Мощность кол-ва операций ( MOp ) = K * Мощность входных данных ( MD ), и где K - среднее кол-во операций на единицу входных данных...

Таким образом - при любом, сколь угодно большом, MD, MOp - всегда конечно.

Comment: "при любом, сколь угодно большом", но конечном. Т.е. при конечном MD, MOp тоже конечно. А при бесконечном...

Comment: Во-во, перепутали бесконечное со сколь угодно большим. См. учение Аристотеля об aeternitas actualis et aeternitas potentialis. Кстати, это основа матана.

Comment: Потенциально бесконечное MD -> потенциально бесконечное MOp. Кроме того не у всех алгоритмов количество операций пропорционально количеству входных данных. Что-то я не слышал пока об алгоритме сортировки со сложностью O(n) :)

UPD. Я не знаю что такое потенциально или актуально бесконечно, я знаю что такое ограниченное значение/функция или бесконечное значение или функция стремящаяся к бесконечности. Количество комментариев ограничено, поэтому дискуссию предлагаю завершить.

Comment: Если сравнить функции факториал N и сумма натуральных чисел больше N, то первая - потенциально бесконечна, а вторая - актуально бесконечна

Comment: О чем вообще спор? Любой реальный алгоритм, выполняемый на реальной ЭВМ, по определению должен иметь конец. Не умеют современные машины работать ни с потенциальной бесконечностью, ни с реальной.

Answer (score 5):

Некоторые задачи (например обход дерева, перебор вариантов и т.д.) достаточно просто (я бы даже сказал, элегантно) решаются с помощью рекурсии. Те же задачи могут решаться с помощью цикла, но с бОльшими усилиями со стороны программиста и примерно с такими же затратами памяти на запоминание предыдущих состояний.

Если компилятор языка программирования не поддерживает оптимизацию хвостовых рекурсий, то хвостовую рекурсию лучше преобразовать в цикл вручную.

Comment: Более уместным при обходе дерева является цикл + собственный стек, что избавляет от доп. вызовов функций и снижает зависимост от стека вызовов.

Comment: О чем я и говорю.

Comment: Читал по диагонали... Действительно, вы об этом и говорили)