# В каких случаях рекурсия более эффективна итерации ? (java)

Tags: java, циклы, рекурсия

В каких случаях рекурсия более эффективна итерации ? (java)

Comment: Только когда задачи сложно решить итеративным путем.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Польза рекурсии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/66528/Польза-рекурсии/66561)

Answer (score 5):

Однозначно, когда работаете с древовидными структурами и вы не знаете сколько вложенностей. И без рекурсии вам никак по нему не пройти.

Comment: Рекурсию всегда можно заменить итерацией и наоборот. Но, конечно, в определённых случаях рекурсивный код проще и понятнее.

Comment: Допустим вы считываете папку, а в ней файлы и еще папки и так далее...и вам надо считать все имена файлов, не зная вложенности, как вы это сделаете с итерацией?

Comment: Например, с помощью цикла while и явного стека или очереди - туда складываются папки, по окончанию цикла сканирования хранилище проверяется - если оно не пустое, оттуда извлекается папка и следующий оборот сканирования идёт внутри неё.

Comment: Да, с этим случаем согласен, вы правы, но допустим вариант, когда каждый узел должен возвращать ответ и его нужно использовать в предыдущих вложенности. Пример: паттерн композит(вычисление формулы, где узлом может быть число или знак и вам нужно рассчитать значение, думаю там не получится итерациями обсчитать выражение), паттерн цепочка обязанностей(например сам Filter в JavaEE)

Comment: В теории вычислений есть такая теорема, что все алгоритмы, представленные в рекурсивном виде, можно представить в итеративном и наоборот.

Answer (score 3):

Все, что можно решить рекурсией, можно решить итерацией. Но дополнительный минус рекурсии состоит в том, что при ее использовании аппаратный стек системы проваливается все глубже и для больших наборов данных это чревато падением приложения. Так что практического смысла рекурсия не имеет, только как учебная задача с целью более полного осознания возможностей программиста. Пользуйтесь циклом и Ваш стек никогда не провалится. А если ваши промежуточные данные надо укладывать в контейнер-стек, то его переполнение можно контролировать программно, в отличие от аппаратного стека системы.